What is the field "description" in Spring Boot Actuator Health Endpoint
I am currently developing an application that is running on Spring Boot 2.7.5 and am looking into the Actuator endpoints.
When I call /actuator/health I get the following response:
{
  "description":"",
  "status":"DOWN"
}

For the life of me I can not figure out where the field "description" comes from and how I can modify or even hide it. I already tried to look at the documentation and other StackOverflow threads.
Does someone know where it might come from?

The health API response including an empty description might be a default behavior. This could be either there are no details available about the status or, based on configuration, it is not exposed due to security reasons.
If you want to set a description in the response of health actuator API you have two options:

Implement a custom HealthIndicator (org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator). Implement the health() method and return the appropriate status and detail field. Then register the custom HealthIndicator.
Use a HealthEndpointCustomizer (org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointCustomizer). Override the customize() method and then override the health() method of HealthContributor to return the appropriate status and details field.

With these hints please search for code samples and proceed.
